# Compute Markov Chain by given stationary vector

Tags: python, markov-chains, mcmc

I'm doing homework in Monte Carlo course and I'm asked to find a matrix of Markov chain with 6 states namely
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
such that after long enough period of time we have spent time  proportional to the numbers
5, 10, 5, 10, 25, 60
in each of the states.

I see that this is the stationary vector that we get if we have the transition matrix. I have to use Metropolis algorithm, but all the explanations and examples I find are based on Metropolis-Hasting algorithm.

Pseudocode of the algorithm that I have:

```
select x
 Loop over repetitions t=1,2...
 select y from Nx using density Gx
 put h=min(1, f(y)/f(x))
 if U ~ U(0, 1) < h then x <- y
end loop
```

I'm looking for a step by step explanation how to implement the algorithm for the given problem, preferably in python!

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is your specific *technical* question?

Comment: I tried to find simple implementation of the algorithm so I can understand the concept, since all I have about it is a piece of pseudocode in my textbook which I can't understand.

Comment: If you post the pseudocode, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Just added the pseudocode as edit to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The algorithmic approach

The standard approach to computing the stationary distribution of a Markov Chain is the solution of linear equations, e.g. as described here https://stephens999.github.io/fiveMinuteStats/stationary_distribution.html.
The solution to your problem is the same in reverse - solve the same equations, except that in your case, you have the stationary distribution but you don't have the transition probabilities/rates.

The problem with this approach, however, is that you may construct a system of linear equations with much more variables than equations. This severely reduces your options regarding the topology of the constructed Markov Chain.
Fortunately, you seem to have no constraints on the topology of the constructed Markov Chain, so you can make some compromises. What you can do is disable most transitions, i.e. give them zero probability/rate, and only enable one transition per state. This may produce some kind of a ring topology, but it should ensure that your system of linear equations has a solution.

#### Primitive example

Consider stationary distribution ***Pi = ( x = 1/3, y = 1/3, z = 1/3)***

Construct your system of linear equations as

```
Pi(x) = 1/3 =  Pr(y,x) * Pi(y)
Pi(y) = 1/3 =  Pr(z,y) * Pi(z)
Pi(z) = 1/3 =  Pr(x,z) * Pi(x)
```

In this case a solution is ***Pr(y,x) = Pr(z,y) = Pr(x,z) = 1*** and the obtained Markov Chain just boringly loops from ***x*** to ***z*** to ***y*** and back to ***x*** with probability 1.
Note that the number of fitting solutions may be infinite (even for the reduced system of linear equations as shown in the example), e.g. in this case the probabilities/rates can be any positive value as long as they are all equal.

#### So, step by step solution

1. Construct the system of linear equations as described.
2. Solve the constructed system of linear equations
3. The solution of your constructed system of linear equations describes a Markov Chain you are looking for. Trivially reconstruct the entire transition matrix, if you want to.

Comment: Is this pertinent to his question though? He said that he must use Metropolis sampling to recover the desired transition matrix.